# How to set alias for "jupyter notebook" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, jupyter-notebook

Each time when I want to start ipython notebook, I have to type "jupyter notebook" in the Windows Command Line `cmd` or `powershell`. Is it possible to set an alias? I tried to do this in `powershell`:

```
New-Alias nb "jupyter notebook"
```

`nb` failed because `powershell` could not recognize `jupyter notebook` as cmdlet or function.

So how to set alias and save it in `powershell`? Is there any better idea to start `ipython notebook` on Windows?

Comment: Possibly it doesn't like it because it includes an argument, not just the executable name? Try with `jupyter-notebook` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the path to the executable file instead of "jupyter notebook" because the program isn't in your $env:path.

```
new-alias nb "C:\SomePath\JupyterNotebook.exe"
```

And you need to place this line in your Powershell profile (~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) so it runs every time you start Powershell.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to add: `New-Item -path $profile -type file –force
` to create a profile, and `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
` to allow execution of scripts.

Comment: Use `where.exe jupyter-notebook` to find out where it is from powershell.

Comment: This will not work well for conda environments. Each conda env has it's own jupyter-notebook.exe file, but this would run the same base env file every time.

Answer (score 1):

First, open your PS profile:

```
notepad $profile
```

If this command opens notepad with a dialog box stating "The system cannot find the path specified.", then do `new-item -type file -path $profile -force` and repeat the command `notepad $profile`.

Then, you can add an alias:

```
Set-Alias -Name jn -Value jupyter-notebook
```

The `jupyter notebook` command and `jupyter-notebook` should be equivalent.

If you have not enabled the running of scripts, you will also need to open a PowerShell as administrator and run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`. Otherwise, you will see an error like `File C:\Users\...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.`

Now when you open a new PowerShell, you can type `jn` and it runs Jupyter Notebook (the `jupyter-notebook` command).

Another method is to create a function in your $profile file:

```
function jn()
{
    jupyter notebook
}
```